# Perform N tests in randomized order for random permutation [Python]

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, random, data-structures, permutation

I was asked the following question in an interview recently, which was a lot more vague and after asking clarification questions came down to this:

```
We have to perform N tests [1, 2, ... N] but in randomized order. 
We have access to two functions test(x) and rand(x) which both take an integer. 
test(x) returns if the current test was succesful or not and rand(x) returns a random integer 
from 1<= rand(x) <= x. 
The tests fail because of the sequeunce of tests carried out and we want to figure out which 
sequences are bad and which sequences are good. 
Basically our task is to generate a sequence of test while carrying them out and return the 
sequence either when the test failed or when all tests are done.
```

I understand that the problem could be simplified by calling rand(N) just once, say x = rand(N) then we get the xth permuation of the seuence (1...N) and then call the test() function on this sequence reutrning only the part of sequence that finished successfully, this is deterministic and can be done in O(N) time. 
Is there a better approach / solution?

Comment: There are `N!` permutations of `1..N`, which means that `x = rand(N)` can generally only specify a tiny fraction of them.  Second saying that you'll just choose the `x`th permutation begs the question of how you find that permutation. I suspect that they wanted you to demonstrate that you know how to do a Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: Interesting, I think you might be right.